# PhpStorm - creating project for Extbase

Tags: typo3, phpstorm, extbase

I am developing a TYPO3 Extbase extension with PhpStorm. I am getting hundreds of notifications saying that Field x could not be found e.g. `Field 'request' not found in DownloadController`.

The [official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/1-Installation/3-configuring-your-ide.html) only covers NetBeans and eclipse.
How does it work in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 2):

1. Add TYPO3 Sources

   - Open your Project Tree (ALT-1)
   - At the end you find "External Libraries" -> RightClick -> Configure PHP include Paths -> add your TYPO3 source path

Set the right php version there as well

2. PHP Docs Comments

Be sure to use the right php annotation headers for every function - PHPStorm resolves them for the parameter info, and ExtBase uses them as well.

Example from the TYPO3 Core:

```
/**
 * Returns the absolute filename of a relative reference, resolves the "EXT:" prefix
 * (way of referring to files inside extensions) and checks that the file is inside
 * the PATH_site of the TYPO3 installation and implies a check with
 * \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::validPathStr().
 *
 * @param string $filename The input filename/filepath to evaluate
 * @param bool $onlyRelative If $onlyRelative is set (which it is by default), then only return values relative to the current PATH_site is accepted.
 * @param bool $relToTYPO3_mainDir If $relToTYPO3_mainDir is set, then relative paths are relative to PATH_typo3 constant - otherwise (default) they are relative to PATH_site
 * @return string Returns the absolute filename of $filename if valid, otherwise blank string.
 */
public static function getFileAbsFileName($filename, $onlyRelative = true, $relToTYPO3_mainDir = false)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, there is one problem left. The typo3 installation and thus extbase is on a remote ftp server, can I still include it? I see no option which says "select from ftp server" or similar.

Comment: You have to download the code to be able to include it as library. Normally you just need the code of the `extbase` and `fluid` extensions

Comment: I usually have a local copy for development, and a extra folder with all typo3  source codes (in different versions). Download TYPO3 sources from here: https://get.typo3.org/, then unzip and link them to your project. 
Additional PHPStorm hint: Tools->Deployment->Configuration: add your FTP server here, then you can upload, download, merge, compare and everything you need. But beware - "Automatic Upload" on every change is tempting but might be dangerous!