# Fluid with PhpStorm view helper can't be found

Tags: typo3, phpstorm, fluid

My PhpStorm IDE does not recognize the fluid view helper. Currently working with PhpStorm 2017.3.3

I installed the Fluid Plugin from sgalinski and added in the Schema and DTDs following xsd file https://fluidtypo3.org/schemas/fluid-master.xsd and linked it to following URI http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers

Does anyone know how I can fix this? It would be great when autocompletion would work for fluid html files

[image: View helper can't be found]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the Typo3 core as external library in your PhpStorm Projekt.

Comment: Nice I added the sysext folder as an external library and now the autocompletion works perfect. Thank you very much

Comment: Note to self: When adding the TYPO3-soures via git, one hast to run a composer install... and do not forget to "export COMPOSER_ROOT_VERSION=[version number]", see documentation for details: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-contributionworkflow/main/en-us/Setup/SetupTypo3.html (otherwise the composer install fails)

Comment: Like me, if you don't know how to do it, check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44497647/3365523

Answer (score 1):

Have a look for these blog posts:

- http://insight.helhum.io/post/85031122475/xml-schema-auto-completion-in-phpstorm
- http://insight.helhum.io/post/130270697975/updated-fluid-schema-urls

Answer (score 1):

You may also check out the PhpStorm Plugins - there is one available for FLUID.
https://www.sgalinski.de/typo3-produkte-webentwicklung/typo3-fluid-phpstorm-intellij/